# netbeans is not starting

Tags: 11.10, java, netbeans

I am using ubuntu 11.10 and installed netbeans today. The installation completed without any errors. But when I double click on the net beans icon in my desktop... the program doesn't start. What should I do to make net beans working?

Comment: It might be more informative to run NetBeans from the command line.  That way you can see the error message(s).

Comment: After running in command line I got
Canot find java please use the --jdkhome switch
what should I do now?

Comment: I'm not familiar with NetBeans or Java installation on Ubuntu.  So someone else will hopefully answer this.  But have you tried using the suggestion?  What happens if you use the `--jdkhome` switch when starting NetBeans from the command line?

Comment: nothing special.... same result

Comment: Maybe it is a silly question, but do You have Java installed? If yes was it one from ubuntu software center? Is Your netbeans installed from USC as well?

Comment: depending on the install/configuration sometimes you have to tweak environment variables to point to the jdk/jre you have installed.  i don't remember when i did it, but i seem to remember it being a little hellish.  i haven't had this problem in a while though

Comment: @Misery Yes without jdk and jre installed in my system netbeans setup won't start.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!